# How to add authentication to SMTP script?

Tags: php, smtp

I'm using this script that calculates total storage used at host server and sends email with details.
It always worked so far with different servers but a new one seems to require authentication for sending the email.

```
<?php

$filePath = "./";

$total = 0;
$d = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
  new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($filePath), 
  RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);

foreach($d as $file){
  $total += $file->getSize();
}

    $to      = 'test@gmail.com';
    $subject = "Storage " .number_format($total/1048576, 2);
    $message = "Storage " .number_format($total/1048576, 2);
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .="Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"ISO-8859-1\"\n";
    $headers .= 'From: XYZHost <test@domain.com>' . "\r\n" .
                'Reply-To: test@domain.com' . "\r\n" .
                'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    ini_set("SMTP", "mail.domain.com");
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Delivery fails with this error:

```
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550-Verification failed for <account@xyz.hosting>
 550-Called:   ---
 550-Sent:     RCPT TO:<account@xyz.hosting>
 550-Response: 550 5.1.1 User unknown: account@xyz.hosting
 550 Invalid sender <account@xyz.hosting>
```

Is there a way for adding authentication here?

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, dsl225.

PHP [mail()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) **does not usually allow you** to use the SMTP server of your choice, **and it does not support SMTP authentication** — required by many mail servers today — at all.

I would recommend  the famous PHP 3rd party package; [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) for your needs.

Comment: Thanks, will try PHPMailer then. Strange because the above script works with a dozen different hosts since many years but it's maybe time to change habits...